# Latest way to connect to a database

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, database-connection

Given that you have a green field project to create.  You are using all of the latest tools; Visual Studio 2015 + SQL Server 2014/16.  How would you connect to the database?   TableAdapter?  DataAdapter? ADO.NET?  Would you use a graphical tool .XSD files or strictly everything in code?

I know it's a broad question but I would like to keep up with the market changes so it would be nice to get an overview of latest and best practises.
I see approaches like WPF + MVVM as new but not successful as people stick to Windows Forms, so what's the trend in database access?

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2015 the answer I found is "Code First Entity Frameworks".   Using it's own SQL for the bulk of the CRUD work and even more advanced SQL until SQL Stored Procedures are more advanced for security etc.

regards,